# Can I use AWS Route 53 with an .ai domain name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have an .ai domain name I've registered through another registrar. I've noticed .ai is not on [Amazon's list of TLDs](https://d32ze2gidvkk54.cloudfront.net/Amazon_Route_53_Domain_Registration_Pricing_20140731.pdf).

Can I still transfer my domain name to Route 53?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Route53 as DNS for your .ai domain, however, you have to use another domain registry to register the domain. Route53 offers both a DNS service and domain registration and these services can be used independently.

Comment: Does that mean, once you register your .ai domain with another registrar, you can then transfer it to Route53?

Comment: You can't transfer the registration to Route53, but you can handle the DNS records in Route53. These are different things; one is the registration of the domain and paying for owning a certain domain, the other is for handling the nameserver traffic. Often these services are combined in an offering, but this doesn't have to be the case.